# Quick way to pass information between projects

Tags: c#, .net-core

Protoyping a frontend that polls backend for objects and then shows and animates the objects in the web browser in realtime.

To do this I have a traditional frontend.

Since I'm just trying out stuff I don't want to set up a database. But I want to be able to add objects dynamically to make sure the frontend reacts when there is new data added. So I made a console application that will work like an admin panel.

I'm looking for a easy an quick way to move data between projects. My first idea was to have a class with a static list with objects that the admin console could update. But I realized that its not possible because the two projects won't share the same static class.

So I thought about serializing and saving the objects to a file and the projects can read and write to the same file. That works but I had problems getting the projects to find the same path since they are in different build folders. I solved that by changing their build folders so that they build to the same folder.

My main question is if there is a simple way to give both projects access to a create and read from a folder outside the solution, for example `c:\ObjectStash`. The solution I use now requires the build folder to be changed and I don't want to have to do that in the future if I reuse this when I try prototypes.

Also I'd love to hear if you have had the same need and how you solved it.

Comment: What is your stack? ASP NET Core, react, angular, jquery, bootstrap, wpf, xamarin, dart, swift, flutter, react native? What's your font end in and what's your back end in? Clarify what you mean by "traditional frontend" please.

Comment: ASP.NET Core. But really im looking for a way to be able to do this with any .NET project since this is how i try new ideas. The frontend is MVC and Angular

Comment: The Repository pattern comes to mind...

Comment: You could use redis as an intermediary store. But your proposed solution of writing to files should work. What is stopping your program from writing outside the folder, as long as you specify a valid path and the program has read/write access to that path, it should work.

Comment: Use an [absolute path](http://www.linfo.org/absolute_pathname.html). RPC and IPC come to mind but they are overkill if it's for prototyping purposes. But [file watchers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2#watch-for-changes) and absolute paths should solve the problem as you describe it. But if you want to prototype EF Core, the regular method is to use an [in-memory data provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/).

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a set of API from your web application dedicated to manage the test object, then use the console to drive that API and create the object you want. Basically any sort of RPC ( included gRPC ) can be used to make the console application communicating with your web app.